# Problem occurred while updating ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, updates, 18.04

Today I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my HP laptop. And I wanted to check for updates so I used "sudo apt update" and it threw errors as follows,

```
Err:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
502 Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1562::1c 80]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
502 Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
502 Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
502 Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
502 Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
```

I tried "Main Server" and also Indian Server. I think both are down today, Is anybody facing the same issue? 
I'm using some mirror server now. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Wait a few minutes and try again. Servers need to sync, too. Using a closer mirror is a good idea anyway.