# apt-get update throwing errors

Tags: apt

I am trying to run `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y` but it is throwing series of errors. I am new to Linux environment.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                
Err:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::16 80]
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease   
502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease
502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch 
http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  502  
Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic- 
updates/InRelease  502  Connection timed out [IP: 
2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
W: Failed to fetch 
http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/InRelease  502  
Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful- 
updates/InRelease  502  Connection timed out [IP: 
2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic- 
backports/InRelease  502  Connection timed out [IP: 
2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
W: Failed to fetch 
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  502  
Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::16 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic- 
security/InRelease  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 
80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful- 
security/InRelease  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 
80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old 
ones used instead.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission 
denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are 
you root?
```

Thank You

Comment: Old *unanswered* question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046228/problem-occurred-while-updating-ubuntu-18-04 for the main bunch of errors. For the root errors you need to put `sudo` in front of the 2nd command (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Is this the first/only time you have had connection errors?

Comment: I am getting these errors from tomorrow after I installed VirtualBox. Is there any mirror to these sources? And how can I change them? Thank you

Comment: It looks like you don't have a working internet connection. Is this a real machine or are you running a virtual machine in virtual box (I don't understand your virtualbox reference sorry).  I'd suggest trying to ping a web site using ip.address (say 8.8.8.8 or google.dns), then try with a human.address (say google.com) - do any get thru. If first does, second doesn't you have a DNS error. If none get thru you have networking issues you must correct first.

Comment: I do have a working internet connection. I am able to ping www.google.com. I am running Ubuntu on the physical machine. Is there any chance that the error is because of Ubuntu server problem ?

Comment: You are unwisely using sources from different releases of Ubuntu: *artful* and *bionic*.  Don't do that. Stick with one release. While not responsible for your network problem today, mixing versions will surely break your system someday.

Comment: If the unlikely event it is the servers (should only be temporary if it is!), you can change the mirrors https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main otherwise, you may have a networking issue, especially if you have to sign into the network or proxy through a browser or similar, or a weird firewall/filtering somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/)

Answer (score 2):

Your command line contains *one*  occurrence of `sudo` but also `&&`. In this case, `sudo` only applies to the former command, not the part after `&&`. Add `sudo` to the latter command, too.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

However, there is at least one more problem:

```
502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
```

which means you should [check your network connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862865/sudo-apt-update-stuck-0-connecting).

Generally, you should run commands manually one by one (i.e. avoid `&&`, `-y` etc.) to diagnose problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try these commands:

```
sudo -i
apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
mv lists lists.old
mkdir -p lists/partial
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```

Comment: Won't solve a timeout issue.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Thank you for this code, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.